# Android updating single row - strange behaviour

Tags: android, android-listview

I have implemented custom adapter and doing some async operation for image downloading. I have also implemented [PullToRefresh - Nillson](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh).

This is what I do for update

```
int startRow = mainListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
int endRow = mainListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
Log.e("IMAGEURL", "position: " + curPosition + " " + "startRow: " + startRow + " " +       imageInfo.imageUrl);
if (curPosition >= startRow && curPosition <= endRow & imageInfo.holderPosition == curPosition) {
View rowView = mainListView.getChildAt(curPosition - startRow);
```

Strangely, rowView returns me PullToRefresh top relative layout instead of my list's row view. Here is debug info as I don't have ant progressbar in my view and it exact matches with PullToRefresh top layout.

```
[0] ProgressBar  (id=830008126840)  
[1] ImageView  (id=830008129008)    
[2] TextView  (id=830008130288) 
[3] TextView  (id=830008131616)
```

And this only happens when I have no scroll in my listVew (all rows are visible no hidden rows). In case if I increase the number of rows beyond visible numbers  I get my rowView on mainListView.getChildAt(curPosition - startRow) but not the right one because at position 0 mainListView.getFirstVisiblePosition() gives me 1 which should be actually zero.

More details:

PullToRefresh Library add one extra row on the top of user's listView rows it takes place at index 0.

It also changes getCount() and gives (original rows + 1 extra)

Edit:

I have removed PullToRefresh everything works fine and getFirstVisiblePosition() gives correct position. Images are mapping to right rows.

But I need pull to refresh. Still looking for answer.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from offsetting those position appropriately to take in consideration the extra row inserted by the library.

Comment: True. This what I have done but it is not very neat solution.

Comment: Well if you plan to use that library then that is the neatest solution you could get(unless you implement your own `PullToRefreshListView` or modify the existing library to exhibit the default behavior of a `ListView`).

Comment: You can try other PTR libs like https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh